# Lightbox Issue with Non-Linked Images

Tags: wordpress, lightbox

For awhile now, I have been trying to figure out a way to get lightbox working for images on our Wordpress site. The issue is that normally it would work if the image is being `<a href="">` to itself. However, most of our images are not linked. So I was wondering what would be the easiest way to go about this.

Much thanks everyone!

Comment: Probably you can use `javascript` to open **lightbox**.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?